# Can ‘attribute A to B’ be used as ‘attribute to B A?’

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

The article I read uses ‘attribute A to B’, but it uses attribute A to B as attribute to B A. is this correct?

Also, here’s the article.

> Delay is a necessary component of procrastination. This means not only that someone who procrastinates fails to do something that she previously intended to do, but it also requires that she has not given up entirely on completing the task. Deciding not to do something ever is not procrastination, no matter how irrational or self-defeating this decision is. Note further that delaying a task needs to be distinguished from departing from a scheduled time. Schedules and deadlines are means of making explicit and specific our temporal intentions, but we can delay doing something even if our plans are rather vague. For a person’s behavior to count as delay, however, it must depart significantly from the intention and it must be possible to **attribute to the individual an intention to actually do something to advance a goal.** Someone who had a strong desire to climb Mt. Everest but never did anything to advance that goal would not count as procrastinating

Comment: also. i want to ask how ‘attribute A to B’ is used in this article.

Comment: "Attribute to B A" violates the 'rule' "never place anything between a verb and its object." This is ***not*** a rule, merely a guideline, and it's routinely violated when the object is long, as it is in your example. See the answer to this question: [Placing adverb between object and verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348146/placing-adverb-between-object-and-verb).

Comment: While "attribute to B A" is too stark, the bolded portion makes sense because of what leads up to it.

Comment: "Render unto Caesar the things that are Caesar's ...." has a long pedigree, but "Give to me it" will get you some very funny looks.

Comment: What is the source of this article, please?

Comment: It's just a confusing set up sentences.  First the author discusses why an intention is needed to achieve a goal.  After that is set up, you expect the author to give the example about Mt. Everest which is true, but he gives an example of the opposite.  He should have given both examples and have been clearer on what goes with what

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t know the exact souce of this article.

Comment: @Kahotep Where did you find or read it? was it online? if so, can you provide a link?

Comment: I'm sure there's been a previous question about this but can't find it at the moment. The basic principle is that the shorter expression goes first if there is a big difference in lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It must be possible to attribute to the individual an intention to actually do something to advance a goal.

is a perfectly valid sentence, grammatically speaking. Perhaps it could be rephrased to low better, but there is nothign wronmg with the grammar.

> To attribute to {X}, a {Y}

and

> To attribute a {Y} to {X}

are both grammatical, the difference is one of style. Depending on the context, one might well work better than the other.

Some examples:

> - To attribute to John a criminal  intent here, would be to go beyond the evidence.
> - To attribute to all men a desire for higher status, is to overgeneralize
> - To attribute Jane Doe's novel to inner feelings of depression, seems to carry psychological analysis to an unjustified level
> - To attribute a painting to a particular artist, one often analyzes aspects of style, such as brushwork, as well as the choice of subject an theme.
> - To attribute a specific intent to a general statement is often to go too far.